# Converting an array of 0 and 1 to integer

Tags: python

I have an array of integers which store only 1 or 0. Is there a direct function in python which would do it?
Suppose the array is [0,1,0,1] then it should return 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've effectively got a bitstring, then you can do:

```
>>> a
[0, 1, 0, 1]
>>> int(''.join(str(i) for i in a), 2)
5
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

Can't think of a single function, but the following is pretty straightforward:

```
In [60]: val = 0

In [61]: for digit in [0,1,0,1]:
   ....:     val = val * 2 + digit
   ....:     

In [62]: val
Out[62]: 5
```

**edit:** The following one-liner does the same job, if a bit slower:

```
In [66]: reduce(lambda x,y: 2*x+y, [0,1,0,1,1])
Out[66]: 11
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sum(j<<i for i, j in enumerate(reversed([0, 1, 0, 1])))
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
a_list = [0,1,0,1]
int(''.join(map(str,a_list)), base=2)
```

Comment: @NPE `join` raises `TypeError` if the sequence item is not a string. Your `reduce` is nicer though.

Comment: @dedoco: So if you call this lambda function with one argument, what is the result? There is a much simpler way to write that. ;-)

Comment: @BasWijnen If I'm not mistaking this `lambda` is repeatedly called with one argument which is an element of the list. You would have to explain what you mean by called with one argument...

Comment: @dedoco: (lambda x:str(x)) is a function, which accepts one argument, and returns the expression str(x). Which is the function str, called with one argument. So instead of (lambda x:str(x))("foo") you can just say str("foo") directly. In your answer, instead of lambda x:str(x), you could just have written str.

Comment: @BasWijnen aahaha =), you are right...i missed that (well on a Saturday morning, what can you do...) will change it.

Comment: Note that this simplification combined with a list which is called `list` is confusing: `map (str, list)` looks like you are using two types as arguments, but `list` is in this case a local variable.

Comment: @BasWijnen this is kinda why there is written `list = [0,1,0,1]` before.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do bit manipulation in Python, be sure to check out this wiki page:

http://wiki.python.org/moin/BitManipulation

And while there is no built-in to do it, the libraries mentioned there (notably python-bitstring) should help you.