# Performing bitwise operations on binary strings made from arrays

Tags: python, numpy

Basically I'm trying to grab 1's and 0's values from an array and perform bitwise operations on that.

```
board = np.array([1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])

for x in board:
    s += str(x)
s = int(s)
```

This is obviously not correct however. This has its own binary value and if I perform bitwise operations on it (eg. >>) I'm shifting the underlying binary.

So how can I dynamically create binary strings to perform bitwise operations on?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: "This is obviously not correct" - don't assume it's obvious, tell us what the result is, what your desired output is, and why you think they are different.

Comment: a numpy array of zeros and ones is a good datastructure for representing a binary number because element-wise operations are easy to perform. unless you run into performance problems with the array, why not keep it as is?

Comment: if your goal is to learn about binary numbers this is good (though it could be argued that you could do it without using numpy to keep it simple). Try to implement operation of addition, binary shifts, comparisons such as > and < etc. manually and what you will learn will be valuable for you

Comment: Well I do know I could implement the binary shifts manually using my array, but is there no way to dynamically create a 0b sort of value from the array? I guess that's my big question. I haven't been able to find anything which would achieve this for me.

Comment: @JohnZwinck. As to why it's not correct, it's because it's taking 1100111etc. as an integer then performing the bitwise shift on the underlying binary value. Which is also a bit odd because I seem to be able to AND integer values eg. 1110 AND 1111 will return 1110

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting an array of 0 and 1 to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659120/converting-an-array-of-0-and-1-to-integer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
board = np.array([1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])

for x in board:
    s += str(x)
s = int(s)
```

int automatically converts to base 10 but you could also use int(s,2) to convert it to base 2. You'd then get the base 10 representation of your base2 number. So int("110",2) would be 6 and 6<<2 would be 24 or 6>>2 would be 1.

Also in terms of making the stringyfication easier yon can use

```
s = "".join(map(str, board))
```